# VBA Excel Internet Explorer capturar tabela (td)

Tags: html

Preciso capturar no IE objeto `<tr class="cab_table">`. Dentro dele, tenho que pesquisar perguntando se parte do texto contém a data `31072017`, e ao encontrar esta data na mesma linha tenho, que clicar no href para baixar um arquivo Excel

```
<a title="Exporta Pdf" href="pesquisaAvisoPagamentoPdf.php?parametro_visualizacao=26902796" target="_blank">
    <img width="15" src="/mercantil/pt_br/img/img_arq_pdf.gif" border="0">
</a>
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: O conteúdo que irá procurar, a data está no TR ou no TD?

Comment: Oi Alexandre está dentro do TD e dentro do TD eu tenho que clicar no href

Comment: O que dispara a consulta no IE é uma macro?

Comment: Já tentou a opção "Obter dados externos" > "Dados da web" ?

Comment: precisa ser em VBA pois, as etapas anteriores estão em VBA... e preciso pesquisar linha a linha se contém data 31072017, caso positivo clicar no href